# Text gets invisible in After Effects

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I try to edit a text but it's going invisible. Only when i render it, its visible. How can i change this behavior?

[image: Text gets invisible.]

Comment: try changing the rendering quality to (Half) or lower. It's the word (Full) to the left of where it says "Active Camera".

Comment: i already tried to change the render quality to half or lower but this did not have any effect on this. when opening the file with cc2017, i got a info message: this project must be converted from version 13.0 (windows 64). dont know if this can cause the problem or if it is a setting somewhere. hm.